# IONIC ANGULAR: Push notifications not working on iOs. Listener is not triggered at all

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, listener, capacitor

I am currently working on a serious mobile app project with a strict deadline. I am using the **Ionic Framework along with Angular** and i have an issue with Push notifications in **iOs** devices.

More specifically the **'pushNotificationReceived'** listener is not triggered like it should when the app is in foreground  and  the **'pushNotificationActionPerformed'** listener is not triggered when the app is in the background in ios.

- Please note the following cases:

[image]

*In the case the app is in the background we receive the notification

*In the case the app is killed we receive the notification and the pushNotificationActionPerformed listener is triggered!

Below you can see my ionic info.

```html
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.7 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1002.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.2.0
   @angular/cli                  : 10.2.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.5
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.7

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.3.0) : 0.3.0

System:

   ios-sim : ios-sim/9.0.0 darwin-x64 node-v12.16.1
   NodeJS  : v12.16.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 7.12.1
   OS      : macOS Catalina
   Xcode   : Xcode 12.4 Build version 12D4e


  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

- Push Notification with Firebase Plugin: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/guides/push-notifications-firebase

I am looking forward for your replies.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you [activate push notifications in xcode](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devdfd3d04a1?sub=dev73a37248c)?

Comment: Yes i did. The issue is still there. Did you manage to make it work?
Can you provide a solution?